# I cannot commit changes in docker image

Tags: linux, docker, containers, ubuntu-16.04

I learn docker from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04 .

And I have a problem in "Step 6 - Committing Changes in a Container to a Docker Image".

When I run command `docker run -it ubuntu` I got interactive shell access to the container and in command line I got for example: `root@aaa73f6c6614:/#` and I can using shell. But when I want commit changes after installing nodejs I have to exit from interactive shell using command `exit` and write in command line: `docker commit -m "node.js" -a "Me" aaa73f6c6614 finid/ubuntu-nodejs` but I got the following error: `Error response from daemon: No such container: aaa73f6c6614/Ubuntu-NodeJS`.

Why I cannot commit changes and how can I do that?

(I use Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 2):

Just need to use container id:

```
docker commit -m "node.js" -a "Me" aaa73f6c6614
```

Then you can tag your container as **finid/ubuntu-nodejs**:

```
docker tag aaa73f6c6614 finid/ubuntu-nodejs:latest
```